# Lab Construction of LED

Tags: visible-light, experimental-technique, light-emitting-diodes, solar-cells

If given a semiconductor with known bandgap, how might someone construct an experimental LED within a lab?  It seems common to prepare solar cells using FTO glass plates with a paste of semiconductor applied, but it seems there is much less literature on the preparation of LEDs.

What is the minimum working construction of an LED possible on a lab scale?  Is there something that prevents a powder semiconductor from functioning rather than more of a wafer?